# Prevent Angular from Encoding Query String portion of URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The question is pretty self explanatory. I basically use `'/'` in a value on the query string of my URL, and angular *(or the browser?)* encodes it as `'%2F'`. Normally I wouldn't fight this, but I've read that `'/'` isn't fully restricted for use on the query string portion, and since this URL will be shared, it would be a lot prettier with `'/'` in place of `'%2f'`. Do you of any way to achieve this? Im using UI-router and the URL's are thus being formatted interally *(i.e. I'm not setting `$location.url()`)*.

Edit: I can show you some code but there's nothing really descriptive on my end. Lets say I have
    `var queryVal = some/place/tobe;`
And a state defined using ui-router with a url such as
    `url: /:foo/bar?q`
Then I'm calling
    `$state.go('state', params);`
Where params is an object with the proper parameters, including the unencoded queryVal.
The problem is that somewhere down the line angular or the browser is automatically turning
    `some/place/tobe`
into
    `some%2Fplace%2Ftobe`
And that encoded version is what shows up in the address bar.

Comment: Could you show the part of your code that is causing the issue?

Comment: Too late, but have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849260/angular-ui-sref-encode-parameter