# Angular ui-sref encode parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My router looks like that:

```
.state('project', {
        'url': '/project/*path',
        'controller': 'ProjectController',
        'templateUrl': '/pages/project.html',
    });
```

but when I use

```
ui-sref="project({path: mypath})"
```

with `mypath=part1/part2` I expect the it to turn into `/project/part1/part2` but instead i get `/project/part1%252Fpart2`.

How can I make it pass parameter without encoding it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it was [described here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1119#issuecomment-64696060), you need to declare custom variable type for URL param in order to have slashes not encoded. Quoting comment from github:

> If you really don't want the slash encoded for you, register a custom type with your regexp and declare item_id to be your custom type, i.e., url: /{item_id:MyType}

```
function valToString(val) { return val != null ? val.toString() : val; }
function valFromString(val) { return val != null ? val.toString() : val; }
function regexpMatches(val) { /*jshint validthis:true */ return this.pattern.test(val); }
$urlMatcherFactory.type("MyType", {
  encode: valToString,
  decode: valFromString,
  is: regexpMatches,
  pattern: /[^/]+\/[^/]+/
});
```

Comment: Do you have any solution how i can disable slash encoding if otherwise (404) state is activated (url: "*path")?

Comment: [Don't specify path for your 404 error page.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25722055/878514)

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem you can change a state by using $location.path(), which has slashes in `stateparams`. For example if our state is like this:

app.js

```
.state('project', {
    'url': '/project/*path',
    'controller': 'ProjectController',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/project.html',
});
```

In this case `path` param may contains multiple slashes .If path=part1/part2 then you get route like this `/project/part1%252Fpart2` by using `ui-sref` or `$state.go()`. So to get correct routing (i.e. `/project/part1/part2`), use $location.path() to change a state.

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="goToMyState()">{{label}}</a>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.goToMyState = function () {
    var path = '/part1/part2'
    $location.path('/project' + path);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

in new [ui-router 1.0](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1) we can use raw:true param which will disable url-encoding of parameter as described [here](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/params.paramtype.html)

```
    //link to state
<md-button ui-sref="content({slug:'hello-world/'})">Hello world</md-button>

$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('SlashFix', {
      raw:    true,
    });


    $stateProvider
      .state('content',{
       url: '/{slug:SlashFix}',
       ...
```

More detailed explanation can be found here:

https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-ui-router-replacing-slash-with-2f-quick-fix