# '/' replaced with %252F in url while reloading $state in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am using ui-router in angularjs for routing. I have url something like this

```
www.example.com/*variable
```

in which variable has a form of `word1/word2`

So the url becomes `www.example.com/word1/word2`

but when i apply

```
$state.reload(); or 
$state.go($state.current,{},reload:true);
```

The forward slash get replaced with `%252` and url becomes

```
www.example.com/word1%252Fword2
```

why it is happening and what can be the solution for this?

Comment: hey can you provide the code dude.?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849260/angular-ui-sref-encode-parameter

Comment: I tried this solution but regex pattern  is not working. i am using  `{variable: .* }`. How to make it work in $urlMatcherFactoryProvider ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting location to false?

`$state.go($state.current,{},{reload:true, location: false});`

Since you're specifying URL parameters, perhaps they're being re-written in URL encoded format.  The UI Router docs state

> location Boolean or "replace" (default true), If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string "replace", will update url and also replace last history record.