# angular $routeprovider endless optional param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider

I'm trying to create file & folder manager using angular-js.
So i need endless optional parameters for folderIds to handling this:
`example.com/drive/1/2/3/4/5/...`

Do we have something like this:

```
$routeprovider.when('/drive/[:folderId?]', {
    controller: 'driveCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/drive.html'
})
```

instead of this:

```
$routeprovider.when('/drive/:folderId1?/:folderId2?/:folderId3?/:folderId4?', {
    controller: 'driveCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/drive.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would use [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), you could define custom parameter type if you want it to contain slashes, as [described here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1119#issuecomment-64696060). You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850473/878514).

For example:

```
$urlMatcherFactory.type("FolderType", {
  encode: function(val) { return val != null ? val.toString() : val; },
  decode: function(val) { return val != null ? val.toString() : val; },
  is: function(val) { return this.pattern.test(val); },
  pattern: /([^/]+\/?)+/ // this should catch /example.com/drive/1/2/3/4/5/ in one param
});

$stateProvider.state('drive', {
  url: '/drive/{folder:FolderType}',
  controller: 'driveCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/app/views/drive.html'
});
```